# Which unsupervised learning method should I use on classification on many point cloud datasets?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, clustering, unsupervised-learning

I have a few abstract and high dimensional point clouds in the form of distance matrices. I want to do unsupervised learning on this dataset.

The problem is, I am not using one distance matrix, but treating each distance matrix as an object, and trying to differentiate between those objects. On one distance matrix it's very simple: we can do k-mean, hierarchical clustering, etc.

An exemplary problem in 3d would be to differentiate a group of 3d point clouds of cats from dogs. In 2d would be to differentiate the pictures from cats and dogs. But what are the state-of-the-art methods to apply it on distance matrices?

Many thanks!

Although that was a general question to which I'm looking for an answer, here are more details on how I obtained the distance matrices: I am actually looking into a bunch of weighted networks. The entries in the distance matrices are approximately indicating the distances from one node to another in those networks. I used Dijkstra algorithm for calculating the distances between nodes.

Comment: Can you tell us in which setting this dataset arises?

Comment: From some weighted graphs (networks). I mapped the nodes of weighted networks to a space of metric

Comment: Can you add that information to the original question, as an edit? preferably with more details about how you did it?

Comment: Done! Please let me know if you have more questions.